# How to execute RemoveAliasMapping in ElasticSearch using JEST

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am trying to remove an alias mapping for an index in ES using jest.

Here is what I have tried :

```
// create Jest Client.

JestClient client = factory.getObject();

// create RemoveAliasMapping Object.

RemoveAliasMapping removeAliasMapping = new RemoveAliasMapping.Builder("oldIndex", "alias").build();
```

After creating the `removeAliasMapping` object, I couldn't find a way to execute it.

If I use the api : `client.execute(removeAliasMapping)`, it says : `The method execute(Action<T>) in the type JestClient is not applicable for the arguments (RemoveAliasMapping)`

Also, I couldn't find any other api exposed to execute `AliasMapping`.

Can anyone help me out with this here? If possible, please put an example too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ModifyAliases modifyAliases = new ModifyAliases.Builder(new RemoveAliasMapping.Builder("oldIndex", "alias").build()).build();
JestResult result = client.execute(modifyAliases);
```